# How do I extend acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I recently replaced acts_as_taggable_on_steroids with acts_as_taggable_on in my application and I keep running into a problem where rails cannot find a class associated with the new plugin. I think this is because I'm using the desert plugin and have extended some of the classes that exist both in the acts_as_taggable_on and acts_as_taggable_on_steroids plugins. I think that desert is not properly extending the new plugin's classes. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? One thing I noticed is that the structure of the acts_as_taggable_on plugin is different. 
Basically I am getting this error:

```
Constant TagList from tag_list.rb not found
```

to fix this I put includes ActsAsTaggable on into the offending controller. Once I do this though, I can't access any of the methods I wrote in m overwritten models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are extending a core class or a class of a plugin, you have to manually require the file you made the extensions in (unless named after rails autoload conventions). And from within that file you have to require the file with the original class definition. Perhaps this solves your problem.